# What is the difference between String::from("abcd") and "string"?

Tags: string, rust, borrow-checker

```
let a = "abcd";
let b = a;
let c = a;
let x = String::from("abcd");
let y = x;
let z = x;
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:13
  |
5 |     let x = String::from("abcd");
  |         - move occurs because `x` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6 |     let y = x;
  |             - value moved here
7 |     let z = x;
  |             ^ value used here after move
```

Am I not supposed to get same error for `a`?